# How to kill background process in android cordova

Tags: android, cordova, process, android-manifest

Basically when i press back button, i'm using a confirm popup to exit from the application. If i press OK, my application has to close and background process should kill

When ok,

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
```

This will close app, but background it will be running.

I have added permission in `Manifest file` for killing the process

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

But not sure where and when it will call. I want to call this when `navigator.app.exitApp()` is happening. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to kill your app?  Its not good practice. The  better user experience is to leave app in BG state. For sure you can clear cache before or destroy your instances ... .

Comment: @MaximShoustin the thing is, whenever i close app(background running) and reopen, my splash screen is not displaying every time i reopen the app. So thought, killing the app will solve my splash screen issue

Comment: We need splash screen just to give to app time to setup stuff. Sometimes OS kills your app in background after some time to release memory but its common behavior and I believe you don't need to do anything in this case. Killing yourself can lead to unpredictable behavior